# Replace first occurrence of space with a TAB

Tags: text-processing

I have a file of the form:

```
acaneeraa a c a n ee r a
acaneeraa a c a n ee r aa
acaneeraa a c n ee r aa
achaldaa a c a l d aa
achaldaa a ch a l d aa
```

I have to replace the first occurrence of a space with a tab.

The expected output is:

```
acaneeraa<tab>a c a n ee r a
acaneeraa<tab>a c a n ee r aa
acaneeraa<tab>a c n ee r aa
achaldaa<tab>a c a l d aa
achaldaa<tab>a ch a l d aa
```

`<tab>` is the tab character and not the text. This tab delimiter separates first field from the second.

I visited the following [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/replace-first-occurrence-of-space-with-a-tab-character-4175556658/), but could not get the output.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e "s/ /$(printf '\t')/" <file
```

Comment: there was green and pink color on the question, some words were cut..What was that?

Comment: @Snowbell: I made an editing to make question clearer and better format.

Answer (score 0):

simply `cat $YOUR_FILE | sed 's/ /\t/' > $NEW_FILE`

Comment: You answer doesn't seem to add much to the one posted an hour ago.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev: it is simpler i think, no need to `$(printf '\t')`